# Eigenvalues of a block matrix given eigenvalues of the blocks

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the eigenvalues of the following $6\times6$ block matrix:

\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B & C
\end{pmatrix}
having zero diagonal terms, where each block is a $3\times3$ matrix of given eigenvalues,
Is their any property I can use?

Comment: There is no known correspondence unless $B=0$ (in this case, take the union of eigenvalues of $A$ and $C$).

Answer (score 4):

It is not determined by the eigenvalues of the blocks.  Consider
$$\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 1 &  -2 \sin(t) \cos(t) & 2 \cos^2(t)-1 & \cos(t)-\sin(t)\cr
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \cos^2(t)-1 & 2 \sin(t) \cos(t) & \sin(t)+\cos(t)\cr
1 & 1 & 0 & \cos(t)-\sin(t) & \sin(t)+\cos(t) & 0\cr
-2 \sin(t) \cos(t) & 2 \cos^2(t)-1 & \cos(t) - \sin(t) & 0 & 1 & 1\cr
2 \cos^2(t)-1 & 2 \sin(t) \cos(t) & \sin(t)+\cos(t) & 1 & 0 & 1\cr
\cos(t)-\sin(t) & \sin(t)+\cos(t) & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0}
$$
where $A,B,C$ all have the same eigenvalues $2, -1, -1$ but the block matrix has characteristic polynomial $\lambda (\lambda + 2)(\lambda -2 - 2 \cos(t)) (\lambda + 2 \cos(t))(\lambda^2 + 4 \cos^2(t) + 4 \cos(t) - 8)$
that depends on $t$.