# How to find the eigenvalues of a symmetric block matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

Suppose we have a symmetric block matrix $A$ where the blocks $A_{ii}$ along the diagonal have known eigenvalues.

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} & \cdots & A_{1n} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} & \cdots & A_{2n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ A_{n1} & A_{n2} & \cdots & A_{nn}  \end{pmatrix}$$

Is there a way to find the eigenvalues of $A$?

[Similar question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307998/how-to-find-the-eigenvalues-of-a-block-diagonal-matrix): In the special case where the off-diagonal matrices are 0, then the eigenvalues are easily found.

[Similar question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3970646/eigenvalues-of-a-block-matrix-given-eigenvalues-of-the-blocks): However, in the case where the diagonals are zero and there are no other constraints on the matrices, it seems we cannot find the eigenvalues. I am hoping my case is easier since all the matrices are symmetric with diagonals not necessarily zero.

Comment: There's nothing special about the fact that the diagonals are zero for "similar question 2"; it will be just as difficult to find the eigenvalues in your case